# Can I infuse my own raisins?

Tags: fruit, drying

I quite like lime-infused raisins (like [these](http://smile.amazon.com/Nakd-Lime-Infused-Raisins-Bags/dp/B009CQW6L4?sa-no-redirect=1)), but they're kind of pricey compared to regular raisins. Are they made by some process I can emulate at home? Is it just a matter of soaking and then drying? Or adding small amounts of liquid? Or is this an industrial process I can't easily replicate?

Comment: I just noticed your "like these" on your question so I clicked and looked at the package. On the back it says citric acid and if I am correct there is something about aroma in the ingredients. So the answer below says lime oil and citric acid and what you could do is soak or just half way cover or spray the raisins with lime juice? Then rub it all 3 together and set it out for a day or two. I'm not familiar with citric acid but I'm sure you can get help with that.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you mean by lime-infused raisins but let me explain what I do to my raisins for scones.  I usually soak them in Gran Marnier Liquour, anywhere from 4 hours to 24 hours.  I put the raisins in a glass bowl or big cup, covering the raisins with the Liquour.  It depends on how much flavor I want the raisins to have.  Then I strain the raisins and set aside the liquour for either another receipe or someone usually wants to drink it.  I put the raisins in the scones.  My nieces and nephews just love them, their moms tell me because it's just like eating booze, and of course, when I make it for them, I do use more raisins and soak them more than 24 hours for the flavor. I use the white raisins.   Now for your question.

YES I do believe that if you squeeze enough fresh lime juice to cover the raisins, you will achieve your goal.  My only tiny problem is that the lime juice might break down the raisins because of the acidity in the lime juice. So, what I would do is try one cup of raisins, cover with fresh lime juice and check in 2 hours, if ok continue, if you want more flavor wait 2 more hours and check again and make sure not only for flavor but for the break down of the raisins due to the acidity.  What raisins did you eat?  White, red, concord, there are so many types, that I am not sure which would hold up to the acidity.

Now for the drying. Put them in a very low temp oven, 200 degrees about one hour, checking every 20 minutes, checking to make sure that they do not burn or put in a food dehydrator. Then let them cool. Look this up on Google also.  I am giving you my own experience.  My Auntie used to soak her raisins for some of her cookies in Brandy, Whiskey, Vodka and whatever liquour she thought would be interesting.  She was an excellent cook and baker and owned a restaurant.  Her booze soaked rice raisin pudding was awesome.

The old way and even today is to put outside on mesh, covered on both side with cheesecloth so insects and birds or other undesirables will not get to.  This might take a little while,  a few days to a week or two depending on hot it is outside. I would check this every day or so also.

You could also let them stay plump, leave in the fridge, and take out and eat what you want as you want it.  A little juicy but still tasty.  Sounds delicious and in a fruit salad.  I bet this would be awesome.  I have a lemon tree and white raisins and will try this out myself this week.  I bet this will be a big hit!  Good Balance with sweet fruit.  Hope this info helps you.

Comment: Another thought I had was to cover your raisins, whatever type you bought, in fresh lime juice, bring to a boil, simmer for 5 minutes, turn off heat, then let sit till cools. Strain liquid into bowl and put raisins on a sheet pan. Put in oven on 200 degrees for about 20 minutes, take out and let cool. Let stay out for a day. Should be ok. If the raisins look too wet after the first 20 minutes, try 20 minutes more then take out, cool and leave on pan for a day, or after the first 20 minutes turn off the oven, if wet, just leave in oven and they should dry out and be ok by next day. Good Luck

Comment: Does the flavor remain through the drying? A lot of flavor compounds are pretty volatile, and I can imagine them evaporating some along with the water/alcohol.

Comment: Of course some of it will evaporate, but not so much as to make a difference.  When I make the scones, I bake them for about 20 minutes. granted the raisins are engulfed in dough but there is quite a punch in them.  So, they should be ok, especially if you let them sit on the sheet pan to dry out after the oven.  I will try this myself with lemon instead of lime probably next week sometime for a fruit salad.  I will let you know how it works out.

Comment: Within scones is very different: the raisins don't completely dry out, and a lot of the flavor that's released will end up in the scones, not lost. I'm not saying it won't work, I'm just saying I don't know exactly how well it'll work.

Comment: In the scones they don't dry out because they are very plumped up, encased in a dough, cooked in a 350 degrees F oven. That's why the kids love it so much. It's after midnight, oh well. I'll do a cup of white jumbo raisins, boil, simmer in fresh lemon juice, lemons from my tree, strain, then put them in the oven at 200 degrees F for 20 minutes, check them out and decide if they need another 20 minutes or just turn off the oven and take out half and leave the rest in the oven. Let's see what happens. I will try to report back in the next day or two. Remember, lemons not limes, similar not same.

Comment: Good news, bad news, got to stay on top of it. First batch I covered 1 cup raisins with lemon juice on high heat, answered phone and they burned in minutes, badly, ugh. 2nd try, kept eye on them, the juice boils faster than water. 3rd try, made a simple syrup 2 sugar 1 water, boiled to half gone, added fresh lemon juice, almost like tart lemonade, THEN added raisins, SIMMERED for about 10 minutes, then put on cookie sheet lined with parchment, of course little gooey, put in 200 degree F oven 10 minutes, left in for about 1 hour, took out, it's not what I expected. To syrupy. It can be done!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to soaking in juice as the other answer mentioned, you might also try tossing them with [lime oil](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HSP1P8G) and citric acid. You'd only need a drop or two, and you'd want to be sure to toss them a lot (or maybe put them in a bag and massage it?) to work the oil around evenly. The citric acid would just be to give them a bit of tartness, and appears to be in the ingredients of the brand you linked to anyway. It would definitely give a strong kick of lime flavor without the risk of making them soggy.